# execfile() for configuration - error no such file or directory

Tags: python, config, execfile

I'm trying to use `execfile()` function to use a file as config file. The file has only a bunch of variables and values. But when I'm trying to use it in my code, it throws `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

This is my code:

```
dictionary = {}
execfile("myConfig.cfg", dictionary)
```

Comment: Enter the full path to `myConfig.cfg`

Comment: @JoeYoung If I were to use the full path, should I go with `os.path.realpath` or `os.path.abspath`??

Comment: Use the magic variable `__file__`.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would rename `myConfig.cfg` to `myConfig.py`.
2. Be sure that your config file and the file trying to get the data are in the same folder.
3. **myConfig.py**

`dictionary={'data1':'value1','data2':'value2'}`

4.Import the data:

`from myConfig import dictionary
print dictionary`

Comment: I used this method at first. I wanted a simpler representation of data, thats why I chose execfile method.